# javascript remove child

Tags: javascript, html

## html code

```
<li id="ioAddOtherRelation">
            <a href="" onclick="return ioAddSetOtherRelation()"class="smallLink">add other relation</a>
</li>
```

and i want the function ioAddSetOtherRelation to remove the a tag

## javascript code

```
function ioAddSetOtherRelation(){
    var bigLi = document.getElementById('ioAddOtherRelation');
    bigLi.removeChild(bigLi.childNodes[0]);
    return false;
}
```

when i press the link for the first time ,nothing happend , but when i press it twice it remove the a tag , i want to remove the a tag in one click

Comment: have you tried setting the child element to a variable then using remove() on that?

Comment: yes i tried and it is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that the first child of your 'li' element is actually a textNode containing the newline and whitespace between itself and the 'a' element. The first time you click, this invisible textNode is removed and the second time you click the 'a' is removed.

You can demonstrate this by removing the newline and whitespace (i.e. put all the HTML on one line with no spaces) - you should see the 'a' disappearing on the first click.

I found that the following modified javascript worked as you intended. Note I've used .getElementsByTagName() to make sure that only 'a' elements are returned. this will return an array like .childNodes would, so I'm taking the first element of the resulting array.

```
          function ioAddSetOtherRelation() {
          var bigLi = document.getElementById('ioAddOtherRelation');
          bigLi.removeChild(bigLi.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]);
          return false;
      }
```

I found FireBug to be very useful in solving this problem (together with console.debug() lines in the JS code) - if you're not already using that I'd recommend giving it a go!

Comment: As Quentin and ranganadh noted, passing the 'a' element itself as a parameter is a much more sensible approach than trying to find it as I posted above.

Comment: thank you man , u make me understand the solution and it works as u said , i accept ur answer , thanks

Comment: My pleasure, and thank you for accepting my answer and getting my rep off the ground so I can vote others up at last :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first time you clicked you removed the text node containing the space in front of the element. You need to make sure the argument you pass to `removeChild` is the one you actually want.

This would be a saner approach to the problem:

```
<li id="ioAddOtherRelation">
    <a href="" onclick="return ioAddSetOtherRelation(this)" class="smallLink">add other relation</a>
</li>

function ioAddSetOtherRelation(element){
   var bigLi = element.parentNode;
    bigLi.removeChild(element);
    return false;
}
```

Getting rid of the intrinsic event attribute and writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) would be better still.

Comment: yes man , u the one , it works , thank you very much ,i will accept the answer after 7 mins

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and send parameter as `this`

Take that `this` in ioAddSetOtherRelation function

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/CsVef/)

Comment: always the solution of my problems are using jQuery :) thank you